# ADB sees my phisycal device, logcat output is present. Android device chooser doesn't

Tags: android, eclipse, device, galaxy

I'm trying to hook up a Samsug Galaxy Ace plus to Eclipse for testing. I'm running MAC OS X. 
I have latest SDK. I have 2 versions of eclipse, the new one and Indigo. Neither of them see the device.

I checked through terminal with "adb devices" to see if the device is present and it is. Eclipse shows logcat output for everything the phone does. The only problem is that when I try to run any app the Android Device Chooser window doesn't see my phone.

I found many posts of this problem but none with these details. I've tried every suggestion I could find. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: If your project isn't compatible with the device (restrictions in manifest), the device isn't shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `minSDK` param of your application less or equals to the Android version of your galaxy Ace?

You can check the `minSDK` in the manifest and the API level [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)